# writing a function to classify a matrix

Tags: python

I would like to write a function with one input represented as a numpy array. The function should classify the matrix as one of (i) one-to-one, (ii) onto, (iii) both (i.e. invertible), or (iv) neither. It should return the classification represented as a string (i.e. either "one-to-one", "onto", "invertible", or "neither").

With this code, I am getting the error "your code did not classify the function correctly." May you please help

```py
def classifier(Matrix):
    # Check if the matrix is square
    if Matrix.shape[0] != Matrix.shape[1]:
        return "neither"  # Not square, cannot calculate determinant
    
    # Calculate the determinant of the matrix
    det = np.linalg.det(Matrix)
    
    # Calculate the rank of the matrix
    rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(Matrix)
    
    if det != 0:
        # If the determinant is nonzero, it's invertible
        return "invertible"
    elif rank < Matrix.shape[1]:
        # If the rank is less than the number of columns, it's neither one-to-one nor onto
        return "neither"
    else:
        # If the rank equals the number of columns, check if it's onto
        if rank == Matrix.shape[0]:
            return "onto"
        else:
            return "one-to-one"
```

Comment: @Chris My function did not classify an onto matrix correctly. How can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to confirm whether the code written by you is correct or not:

```
import numpy as np
def classify_matrix(matrix):
    # Calculate the rank
    rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(matrix)
    # Number of rows and columns
    num_rows, num_cols = matrix.shape
    # Check matrix is square
    is_square = num_rows == num_cols
    
    if is_square:
        if rank == num_rows:
            return "invertible"  
        else:
            return "neither" 
    else:
        if rank == num_cols:
            return "onto" 
        else:
            return "one-to-one"
```

For example usage create numpy matrix:

```
matrix1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
matrix2 = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 4]])
matrix3 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

Print the output function

```
print(classify_matrix(matrix1))
# Output: "invertible"
print(classify_matrix(matrix2))
# Output: "one-to-one"
print(classify_matrix(matrix3))
# Output: "onto"
```